# Jquery animate negative top and back to 0 - starts messing up after 3rd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slide

The site in question is this one:

http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/

When you click on one of the posts (any of the boxes) an iframe will slide down from the top with the content in it.  Once the "Home" button in the top left hand corner of the iframe is clicked, the iframe slides back up.  This works perfectly the first 2 times, on the 3rd click on of a post, the content will slide down, but when the home button is clicked, the content slides back up normally but once it has slid all the way up to the position it should be in, the iframe drops straight back down to where it was before the home button was clicked, I click it again and then it works.

Here is the code I've used for both sliding up and sliding down functions:

```
/* slide down function */

var $div = $('iframe.primary');
var height = $div.height();
var width = parseInt($div.width());
$div.css({ height : height });
$div.css('top', -($div.width()));


$('.post').click(function () {
      $('iframe.primary').load(function(){
            $div.animate({ top: 0 }, { duration: 1000 });
      })

      return false;
 });


 /* slide Up function */

 var elm = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
 var jelm = $(elm);//convert to jQuery Element
 var htmlElm = jelm[0];//convert to HTML Element

 $('.homebtn').click(function(){
      $(elm).animate({ top: -height }, { duration: 1000 });

      return false;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Ajax, like load(), ready() in jquery to control them better?

I am also not sure what you are trying to do with this.

```
var height = $div.height();
$div.css({ height : height });
```

may be you want to get the height of the current window? Where you can get it this way

```
var $dDiv = $('iframe.primary');
var innerH = window.innerHeight;
$dDiv.height(innerH);
```

Also try avoiding naming your custom var with default names like height, width, div, etc... You will confuse yourself and make debugging a pain.

Comment: I used your idea of using ajax and it worked out! thanks buddy